# Photo gallery in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hai,

I am in search of a photo gallery in jquery like the one in the following link http://www.epson.co.in

Could you guess tell me where i can get a plugin like this.

thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+gallery

Comment: Or, if you don't like the Google, you can try the [Duck](http://www.duckduckgo.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a collection of 12 different carousel.

http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/03/12-javascript-3d-carousel-collections.html

pick one

Answer (score 0):

I use this one -

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Very good for customisation!